# html script won't remove from index.html according to AMP Validator but its removed from my index.html on my side

Tags: javascript, html

I have a html script that will not removed from my html. I added this script from siteapps.com and realized it didn't pass amp so i removed it. now everytime i go to amp validate my page, it still says its there and it won't pass. but i HAVE removed the code from my index.html. here is the script:

```
'<script data-cfasync="false">$SA={s:271308,tag_info:"1.0.1-autotag",asynch:1,useBlacklistUrl:1};
(function(){var sa=document.createElement("script");sa.type="text/javascript";sa.async=true;
sa.src=("https:"==document.location.protocol?"https://"+$SA.s+".sa":"http://"+$SA.s+".a")+".siteapps.com/"+$SA.s+".js";
var t=document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];t.parentNode.insertBefore(sa,t);})();</script></head>`
```

here is my html:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html amp lang=en>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8>
<meta name=viewport content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,minimum-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no,minimal-ui">
<title>Rayne Mirrors - Mirrors</title>
<link rel=canonical href="https://raynemirrors.com/index.html">
<meta http-equiv=Content-Type content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
<meta http-equiv=X-UA-Compatible content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
<meta name=description content="Take your home decor to the next level">
<meta name=keywords content="mirrors">
<meta property=og:site_name content="Rayne Mirrors Inc."/>
<meta property=og:title content="Rayne Mirrors Inc. - Mirrors"/>
<meta property=og:description content="Take your home decor to the next level"/>
<meta property=og:image content="https://raynemirrors.com/raynemirrorsinc.jpg"/>
<style amp-boilerplate>body{-webkit-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;-moz-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;-ms-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both}@-webkit-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@-moz-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@-ms-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@-o-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}</style>
<noscript><style amp-boilerplate>body{-webkit-animation:none;-moz-animation:none;-ms-animation:none;animation:none}</style></noscript>
<script async custom-element="amp-analytics" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-analytics-0.1.js"></script>
<style amp-custom>*{box-sizing:border-box;}
.header{background-color:#ffffff;padding:0px;}
amp-img{width:100%;height:auto;max-width:100%;}
.menu ul{list-style-type:none;margin:0;padding:0;}
.menu li{padding:8px;margin-bottom:7px;background-color:#ffffff;box-shadow:0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.24);}
.menu li:hover{background-color:#D1CFCF;}
.aside{background-color:#ffffff;padding:0px;color:#000000;text-align:center;font-size:14px;box-shadow:0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.24);}
[class*="col-"]{float:left;padding:15px;width:100%;}
.row:after{content:"";clear:both;display:table;}
.halfwidth{max-width:800px;}
.halfwidth2{max-width:100px;text-align:center;padding:0px;margin:0 auto;padding-left:0px;}
.halfwidth3{max-width:300px;text-align:center;padding:0px;margin:0 auto;padding-left:0px;}
.halfwidth4{max-width:800px;text-align:center;padding:0px;margin:0 auto;padding-left:0px;}
.halfwidth5{max-width:90px;text-align:center;padding:0px;margin:0 auto;padding-left:0px;}
.halfwidth8{max-width:90px;text-align:center;padding:0px;margin:0 auto;padding-left:0px;}
.halfwidth9{max-width:300px;text-align:center;padding:0px;margin:0 auto;padding-left:0px;}
.halfwidth10{max-width:700px;text-align:center;padding:0px;margin:0 auto;padding-left:0px;}
.halfwidth11{max-width:150px;text-align:center;padding:0px;margin:0 auto;padding-left:0px;}
.halfwidth12{max-width:400px;text-align:center;padding:0px;margin:0 auto;padding-left:0px;}
.rounded-corners{border-radius:20px;}
.amp-wp-title{font-weight:bold;font-size:14px;color:#FF0004;}
.amp-wp-title1{font-weight:bold;font-size:20px;color:#ff0000;}
.amp-wp-title2{font-weight:bold;font-size:20px;color:#0000ff;}
.wrapper{border:2px solid #C1C1C1;border-radius:0px;padding-left:0px;padding-right:0px;}
@media only screen and (min-width:600px){.col-s-1{width:8.33%;}
.col-s-2{width:16.66%;}
.col-s-3{width:20%;}
.col-s-4{width:33.33%;}
.col-s-5{width:41.66%;}
.col-s-6{width:60%;}
.col-s-7{width:58.33%;}
.col-s-8{width:66.66%;}
.col-s-9{width:75%;}
.col-s-10{width:83.33%;}
.col-s-11{width:91.66%;}
.col-s-12{width:100%;}
}
@media only screen and (min-width:768px){.col-1{width:8.33%;}
.col-2{width:16.66%;}
.col-3{width:20%;}
.col-4{width:33.33%;}
.col-5{width:41.66%;}
.col-6{width:60%;}
.col-7{width:58.33%;}
.col-8{width:66.66%;}
.col-9{width:75%;}
.col-10{width:83.33%;}
.col-11{width:91.66%;}
.col-12{width:100%;}
}
html{font-family:"Lucida Sans", sans-serif;}
.footer{background-color:#ffffff;text-align:center;font-size:16px;padding:0px;}</style>
<link rel=icon href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon"/>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon"/>
<script async src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0.js"></script>
<script async custom-element="amp-analytics" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-analytics-0.1.js"></script>
</head>
```

here is the screenshot of my amp validator...

**AMP Validator Screenshot:**
[image]

you can get my link in the screenshot... (not sure if i can post the link to my website)

even page speed websites pick up the same error... What can i do to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the type declaration on the script.

> type="application/ld+json"

```
<script type="application/ld+json" data-cfasync="false">$SA={s:271308,tag_info:"1.0.1-autotag",asynch:1,useBlacklistUrl:1};(function(){var sa=document.createElement("script");sa.type="text/javascript";sa.async=true;sa.src=("https:"==document.location.protocol?"https://"+$SA.s+".sa":"http://"+$SA.s+".a")+".siteapps.com/"+$SA.s+".js";var t=document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];t.parentNode.insertBefore(sa,t);})();</script></head>
```

https://www.ampproject.org/docs/tutorials/create/basic_markup

Comment: i have removed the script from my index.html... but the script still shows on amp test. how can i get it removed?

Comment: also, if i add the script back on my index.html, then it shows TWICE on the amp test. then if i remove it again, it shows ONCE still.

Comment: i just found out something else... nomatter where i put the </head> at in my index.html, the script stays with it... if i removed the </head> then the script goes away from the amp test... WTH...?

Comment: Any Help Or Thoughts?

Comment: @Bobby: I've just checked your website and it still doesn't have the script with the specified type "application/ld+json", please update it accordingly.

Comment: the script that you are looking at has been REMOVED from my index.html. so when you are seeing it, its not actually there. what can i do to remove it permanently?

Comment: Anymore Ideas? I would appreciate it!